# savenv on Beaglebone Black Wireless UBoot

Tags: linux, bootloader, beaglebone

Sorry if i sound like a noob. I got into the bootloader (UBoot) of my Beaglebone Black Wireless and after i set the environment to default `env default -f -a` i then enter the `saveenv` command and get the following error:

> Saving Environment to EXT4... Card did not respond to voltage select!
>   Failed (1)

I do not have an SD card plugged in and am booting from the MMC storage. I was told that UBoot uses the environment from the storage it is booting from. How do I get UBoot to save the environment to the MMC storage and not the SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I got an answer from another forum.

I am quoting it below.

"Well, sadly today u-boot only supports saveenv in one location and one file system type.

If you want to force it for eMMC for your design, you’ll need to patch u-boot, in the file configs/am335x_evm_defconfig

Change

CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_INTERFACE="mmc"
CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_DEVICE_AND_PART="0:1"
CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_FILE="/boot/uboot.env"

to

CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_INTERFACE="mmc"
CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_DEVICE_AND_PART="1:1"
CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_FILE="/boot/uboot.env"

0 = microSD
1 = eMMC"

Link: https://forum.digikey.com/t/question-for-card-did-not-respond-to-voltage-select/2763/4